# Android: How do I refresh the screen using a bitmap from C# code?

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, android-imageview

How do I refresh the screen using a bitmap from C# code?

I wish to show a changing bitmap dynamically, but I see only the final image.

I have searched thoroughly, but not found an answer.

To see what is going on, I have written a noddy program in Visual Studio 2017 which should first show red and then blue, as follows

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      base.OnCreate(bundle);
      // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
      SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

      // The imageView is needed to contain the drawing.
      ImageView image_view = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

      // Create a new image bitmap
      Bitmap drawBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(50, 100, Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);
      drawBitmap.EraseColor(Color.Red);

      // Attach the bitmap to the ImageView
      image_view.SetImageBitmap(drawBitmap);

      // Wait 2 seconds before changing the colour,
      // to give time to see it.
      TimeSpan delayTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);  // 2 seconds
      Task.Delay(delayTime).Wait();

      // Change the color
      drawBitmap.EraseColor(Color.Blue);
      image_view.SetImageBitmap(drawBitmap);

      int k = 0;
  }
```

When I run this program, I see only the blue screen.

If I put a breakpoint at the last line `k = 0` the screen remains black when the breakpoint is hit, and only appears blue when I continue.

Can someone please advise what I need to do to see the screen change colour dynamically?

I know that using `Task.Delay(delayTime).Wait()` in the UI thread is bad practice, but here I am simply trying to work out how to refresh the screen.

Following further investigation, I have tried instead using `Handler` and `Action` as recommended in an answer to the question 'How to run code after a delay in Xamarin Android'

The code now looks like this

```
public class MainActivity : Activity {
    private Bitmap m_drawBitmap;
    private ImageView m_image_view;
    private int m_count = 0;

    private static readonly Color[] colors = new Color[3] {Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue };

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // The imageView is needed to contain the drawing.
        m_image_view = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

        // Create a new image bitmap
        m_drawBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(50, 100, Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);

        long frameStartTime = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime();

        Handler h = new Handler();
        Action myAction = () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting color index to {0}", m_count);

            // the code that I want to delay goes here
            m_drawBitmap.EraseColor(colors[(m_count++) % 3]);

            // Attach the bitmap to the ImageView
            m_image_view.SetImageBitmap(m_drawBitmap);
        };

        h.PostDelayed(myAction, 2000);

        h.PostDelayed(myAction, 2000);

        h.PostDelayed(myAction, 2000);

        // time taken to draw it all in milli-secs
        long drawTime = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() - frameStartTime;

        Console.WriteLine("That took {0} ms", drawTime);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I still see a blue screen. The debug output reports (among other things)

```
Thread started:  #8
InspectorDebugSession(7): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
07-17 11:52:44.260 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9d77e930] worker starting
07-17 11:52:44.283 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9daff930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
Setting color index to 0
07-17 11:52:45.403 I/mono-stdout( 4323): Setting color index to 0
07-17 11:52:45.406 D/Mono    ( 4323): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
07-17 11:52:45.406 D/Mono    ( 4323): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
07-17 11:52:45.406 D/Mono    ( 4323): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
07-17 11:52:45.406 D/Mono    ( 4323): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
Setting color index to 1
07-17 11:52:45.409 I/mono-stdout( 4323): Setting color index to 1
Setting color index to 2
07-17 11:52:45.410 I/mono-stdout( 4323): Setting color index to 2
07-17 11:52:51.285 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9d9fe930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 3
07-17 11:53:19.300 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9d9fe930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
07-17 11:53:33.307 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9d9fe930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 3
Thread finished:  #4
InspectorDebugSession(7): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStopped
Thread started:  #9
InspectorDebugSession(7): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
The thread 'Unknown' (0x4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
07-17 11:54:01.323 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9d9fe930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
07-17 11:54:15.330 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9daff930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 3
InspectorDebugSession(7): HandleTargetEvent: TargetStopped
InspectorDebugSession(7): Disposed
07-17 11:54:46.701 D/Mono    ( 4323): [0x9d9fe930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
Thread finished:  #9
Thread started:  #10
The thread 'Unknown' (0x9) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The time between the messages 'setting color index to ...' is less than 0.01 seconds, so the delay is not working.

The message about how long it all took never appears.

If I place a breakpoint at the last line 'That took ...', and rerun, I see that the elapsed `drawTime` is only 16 ms.

Can anyone please advise what I need to do to make this work, so that I see the successive colors with the intended delay?

Comment: you call `image_view.SetImageBitmap` twice without  giving `image_view` a chance to respond (redraw itself), it will not work, for example use `Handler`s instead, see https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks#handler

Comment: The information in the link you provide relates to Java, not C#. I do not see how to override the `Run` function in class `Runnable` in C#, as this class is sealed. Please advise on how to pass the code to be run into the handler!

Comment: i never used xamarin, but hope this helps: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.OS.Handler.PostDelayed/p/Java.Lang.IRunnable/System.Int64/